# Angular Session Storage Set and Get on same page

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, session-storage

We are using Angular 6 with more than 15 components. While we load page for the first time, the first parent component will trigger a service call and based on the response, we are setting sessionStorage.

And next other components will use the data using get sessionStorage. But sometime, if the service call is delayed, then we will not get the data on other components and end-up with blank data.

**Code in the Parent component:**

```
this.siteConfigurationService.configData(this.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
    const orderActionArr = [data];
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
        this.sessionMgmtService.setSessionItem("configData", data[0]["configData"], 1);
    }
});
```

**Code in another components.**

```
this.sessionMgmtService.configData$.subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (data) {
        this.configData = data;
    }
});
```

**HTML file:**

```
{{configData[0].personName}}
```

sessionMgmtService is another service component where we maintain set and get method for session storages.

We are using the above Subscribe, but it is not helping us. We are getting issue the whenever the service call is delayed.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: how does sessionMgmtService look with set & get ?

Comment: Yes, But we are encrypting data before set to session and decrypting data when try to get it back.

Comment: That i sfine but this much code wil not help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I just updated in my question.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can add `configData$`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.siteConfigurationService.configData(this.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
    const orderActionArr = [data];

    
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {


      this.sessionMgmtService.setSessionItem("configData", data[0]["configData"], 1);

      // you have to emit data or data[0] (whatever) from here so other components will receive it.
      this.sessionMgmtService.configData$.next(data); 

    }
});
```